# Are all databases provided by a SQLiteOpenHelper constructed with the same name within an app guaranteed to be identical?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-context

If multiple activities within an app call the constructor of my SQLiteOpenHelper with themselves as the context argument, can I be sure that they will all access the same database?

For example, let's say I have:

```
package foo.bar;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SQLiteDatabase db = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
      :
  }
}
```

and

```
package foo.bar.baz;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      SQLiteDatabase db = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this).getReadableDatabase();
      :
  }
}
```

Here's in the skeleton of my [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) subclass:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "comments.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    :
}
```

I can't find anything in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29) that guarantees that the two activities get the same database.  On the other hand, I haven't seen any mentions of people getting different databases from contexts within a single application.  Are the database paths guaranteed to be identical?

Comment: you should use a singleton for your DatabaseOpenHelper

Comment: @njzk2 I wondered about that, although the answers are saying it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` has 2 constructors and the second parameter for both of them is the database file name.

If you used the same database file name when using `SQLiteOpenHelper` from different activities, you will get access to the same database.

This is usually taken care of in the constructor of the inheriting class you create - `DATABASE_NAME` is a constant:

```
public MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
```

Comment: You're of course right about the constructors.  I'll fix my post.

I still don't see where I'm guaranteed that using different contexts within the same app give me the same database.

Comment: @espertus It's because you request the same **database file name**.

Comment: what's the context argument used for then?

Comment: It internally allows access to the database, reading the files, etc.

Comment: Thanks, although I still wish it were in the documentation.  Of course, this isn't the first time someone's wished that the Android API were more explicit.

Comment: @espertus Yes, the documentation is not the best. Look at the list of methods for `Context` class, it will become more clear what role it has in accessing the database.

Answer (score 1):

if you do it as the Android folks recommend (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Then yes, all activities within an app will see the same database

Comment: Thanks for the response and the pointer.  I do extend SQLiteOpenHelper in the manner recommended.  I don't see where in the linked documentation it says how the context argument is used.

Comment: @espertus It's not the `context` parameter that matters, it's the `name` parameter of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor.